# Android Drawing Moving Lines

Tags: android, android-studio, android-canvas, draw

I am developing a `game` using `Android Studio` where I need the `blocks` to move from `right` to `left`. I have a file as an input and it contains a `string list` which would look something like this:

`[(160,0;7,58), (160,0;7,59)..]`

The `elements` in this `list` should be seen as `coordinates`, the `1st number` of each pair (in this case `160,0`) is the `coordinate` on the `Y axis` and the `second number` (in this case `7,58` and `7,59`) is the `coordinate` on the `X axis`

The idea of this list is that the `first` number of every pair is the `pitch` heard at that `ms`, which is the second number. And the `lines` that come in from the `right` should arrive at the `left` corner at the time they were heard.

Lets say I someone said one word (with the same `pitch` for this example), the `list` would look something like this

`[(160,0;5,50),(160,0;5,51),(160,0;5,52),(160,0;5,53),(160,0;5,54),(160,0;5,55),(160,0;5,56),(160,0;5,57),(160,0;5,58),(160,0;5,59),(160,0;6,00),(160,0;6,01),(160,0;6,02),(160,0;6,03)]`

Now in this given `list` the `160,0` is the `pitch` of the sound and the second number is `5,50ms`. Now the idea is that the `lines/bars` that come from the `right` side will reach the `left` side at that point. This whole `list` makes one `word` and should be `displayed` as one `block/line` that moves from right to left.

The `blocks` should come in and then disappear (like it is illustrated in the `illustration`), pretty much like `rainfall` or in `tetris` where the `blocks` fall down but instead of hitting the ground they disappear. In the `illustration` you can see one `full block` and the other one is just coming in from the right. The `1st` long block that you see in the `illustration` should move to the left most screen and then gradually `dissapear`.

I drew a little `illustration` of how it should look like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr63c.jpg

Is the best approach to create one `block`, clone it and move it on or `draw` new lines with `"draw"` or can someone tell me how I should approach this.

Comment: need more clarification

Comment: Tried to make it more understandable, hopefully this helps.

Comment: Is there really noone that can help me :(

Comment: does (160,0;7,58) represent a line as - y1= 160, y2= 0 and x1 = 7 and x2 = 58, so that line is from (x1, y1) to (x2, y2)

Comment: No it is just a double x = 7:58 and y=160,0